# How can I test that I have configured ChainedKafkaTransactionManager correctly in my spring boot service

Tags: spring, spring-boot, transactions, spring-kafka

My spring boot service needs to consume kafka events off one topic, do some processing (including writing to the db with JPA) and then produce some events on a new topic. No matter what happens I cannot have a situation where I have published events without updating the database, and if anything goes wrong then I want the next poll of the consumer to retry the event. My processing logic including the db update is idempotent so retrying that is fine

I *think* I have achieved exactly once semantics as described on https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#exactly-once by using a ChainedKafkaTransactionManager like so:

```
@Bean
public ChainedKafkaTransactionManager chainedTransactionManager(JpaTransactionManager jpa, KafkaTransactionManager<?, ?> kafka) {
    kafka.setTransactionSynchronization(SYNCHRONIZATION_ON_ACTUAL_TRANSACTION);
    return new ChainedKafkaTransactionManager(kafka, jpa); 
}

@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
        ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaConsumerFactory,
        ChainedKafkaTransactionManager chainedTransactionManager) {

    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    configurer.configure(factory, kafkaConsumerFactory);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setTransactionManager(chainedTransactionManager);

    return factory;
}
```

The relevant kafka config in my application.yaml file looks like:

```
  kafka:
    ...
    consumer:
      group-id: myGroupId
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      properties:
        isolation.level: read_committed
      ...
    producer:
      transaction-id-prefix: ${random.uuid}
      ...
```

Because the commit order is critical to my application I would like to write a integration test to prove that the commits happen in the desired order and that if an error occurs during the commit to kafka then the original event is consumed again. However I am struggling to find a good way of causing a failure between the db commit and the kafka commit.

Any suggestions or alternative ways I could do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a custom `ProducerFactory` to return a `MockProducer` (provided by `kafka-clients`.

Set the `commitTransactionException` so that it is thrown when the KTM tries to commit the transaction.

**EDIT**

Here is an example; it doesn't use the chained TM, but that shouldn't make a difference.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So66018178Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So66018178Application.class, args);
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so66018178", topics = "so66018178")
    public void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }

}
```

```
spring.kafka.producer.transaction-id-prefix=tx-
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
```

```java
@SpringBootTest(classes = { So66018178Application.class, So66018178ApplicationTests.Config.class })
@EmbeddedKafka(bootstrapServersProperty = "spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers")
class So66018178ApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    EmbeddedKafkaBroker broker;

    @Test
    void kafkaCommitFails(@Autowired KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry registry, @Autowired Config config)
            throws InterruptedException {

        registry.getListenerContainer("so66018178").stop();
        AtomicReference<Exception> listenerException = new AtomicReference<>();
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        ((ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>) registry.getListenerContainer("so66018178"))
                .setAfterRollbackProcessor(new AfterRollbackProcessor<>() {

                    @Override
                    public void process(List<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> records, Consumer<String, String> consumer,
                            Exception exception, boolean recoverable) {

                        listenerException.set(exception);
                        latch.countDown();
                    }
                });
        registry.getListenerContainer("so66018178").start();

        Map<String, Object> props = KafkaTestUtils.producerProps(this.broker);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<String, String> pf = new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(props);
        KafkaTemplate<String, String> template = new KafkaTemplate<>(pf);
        template.send("so66018178", "test");
        assertThat(latch.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)).isTrue();
        assertThat(listenerException.get()).isInstanceOf(ListenerExecutionFailedException.class)
                .hasCause(config.exception);
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class Config {

        RuntimeException exception = new RuntimeException("test");

        @Bean
        public ProducerFactory<Object, Object> pf() {
            return new ProducerFactory<>() {

                @Override
                public Producer<Object, Object> createProducer() {
                    MockProducer<Object, Object> mockProducer = new MockProducer<>();
                    mockProducer.commitTransactionException = Config.this.exception;
                    return mockProducer;
                }

                @Override
                public Producer<Object, Object> createProducer(String txIdPrefix) {
                    Producer<Object, Object> producer = createProducer();
                    producer.initTransactions();
                    return producer;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean transactionCapable() {
                    return true;
                }

            };
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Gary, I have been trying to wire in a MockProducer as you suggest but I haven't been able to get it working yet.

If I don't call `mockProducer.initTransactions()` I get an error:  `MockProducer hasn't been initialized for transactions.`

If I do then I get 
`Could not create Kafka transaction
...
Transaction already started
...
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListenerInTx(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1832)` 

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Or do you know a good example I should look at?

Comment: I added an example that works for me; can you edit the question to show the complete stack trace when you call `initTransactions()`.

Comment: Using your example I managed to get mine working. I think the problem was caused by me confusing the wiring of the producer factory used for my test and the one used by the application. Thank you for your help! (and for all your other answers in the other stack overflow questions I have read recently)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use ChainedKafkaTransactionManager anymore, it is deprecated.

according to docs:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#container-transaction-manager

"The ChainedKafkaTransactionManager is now deprecated, since version 2.7; see the javadocs for its super class ChainedTransactionManager for more information. Instead, use a KafkaTransactionManager in the container to start the Kafka transaction and annotate the listener method with @Transactional to start the other transaction."

In my tests, where I tried to simulate exception in Producer after DB transaction committed, I simply left mandatory field empty in Kafka event (used Avro schema), and in the second test I deleted the topic for producing with the help of Kafka Admin. And then I wrote some asserts to verify that Kafka Listener was called again, when retrying.